# how to make span input group text have the same size in html?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the span for input group text have the same size? I already put the `w-100` in the span class but its not working. How do I fix this ?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Facebook</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.facebook.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Instagram</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.instagram.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.twitter.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Youtube</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.youtube.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>TikTok</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.tiktok.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Other</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try adding a min-width ??

Comment: add `class="d-inline-block"` from bootstrap or `style="display:inline-block;"`

Comment: You cannot set the width of  all the label as the maximum width of label in the list with this layout unless you use some hardcoded vallues in px or something. All the labels are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-width` or `width` for `.input-group-prepend`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Facebook</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text  w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.facebook.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Instagram</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text  w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.instagram.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text  w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.twitter.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Youtube</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text  w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.youtube.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>TikTok</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.tiktok.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Other</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

added `w-50 d-inline-block` classes to `input-group-prepend` div

you can change the w-50 to any width you want.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Facebook</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text  w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.facebook.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Instagram</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text  w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.instagram.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text  w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.twitter.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Youtube</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text  w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.youtube.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>TikTok</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend w-50 d-inline-block">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd;">https://www.tiktok.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Other</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `min-width: 225px;` to all the input-groups. You can adjust the **225px** as needed.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Facebook</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd; min-width: 225px;">https://www.facebook.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Instagram</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd; min-width: 225px;">https://www.instagram.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd; min-width: 225px;">https://www.twitter.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Youtube</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd; min-width: 225px;">https://www.youtube.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>TikTok</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text w-100" style="background-color:#ddd; min-width: 225px;">https://www.tiktok.com/</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Other</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if there is an another div with some long text needs to be added? Can this be treated as generic solution?

Comment: If another div with some long text comes, then the 225px will need to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Yes. So this cant be treated as a generic solution I suppose.

Comment: Yes you're right. This is just a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding padding-right to all the input-group-texts to make them all have equal width or try giving them all a min-width as desired.